# From Mysql table to flask_sqlalchemy db.Model

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Ok ok the table already exists....

Is there any utility to transform a mysql table into a flask-sqlalchemy db.Model without typing?

Answer (score 2):

yes, I personally like `sqlacodegen`, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlacodegen

to install:

```
pip install sqlacodegen
```

to generate ORM code (using MySQL as an example, root user with no password):

```
sqlacodegen mysql+pymysql://root@localhost/your_database_name
```

Comment: You saved me! Thank you.